# Mock ViewModel in MVVM Activity

Tags: kotlin, mockito, android-espresso, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

**Update 29/04/18**

Re-titled for better accuracy. Problem is simple: **ViewModels *cannot* be simply mocked on Activities because they are instantiated in an Acitivity's onCreate(). What is the best way around this?**

Some [related ideas located here](http://www.davidwong.com.au/blog/2017/10/) (unsuccessfully tried to implement)

**Original question**

Using Google's MVVM GithubBrowserSample codebase, I am trying to make an instrument test for checking that a loading state throws up a progress bar. Specifically, a mirror of [the UserFragmentTest.loading() method](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserFragmentTest.java). It's pretty simple stuff, I have tried to match my setup closely to Google's.

However I can see it's not right. Specifically, I can see functions in my ViewModel (VM) are being called when I explicitly ask for them not to be in my test's `@Before` function. I am using Kotlin, Dagger2, and the Architecture Components.

When I run the `UserFragmentTest.loading()` test, I can see the code does indeed call nothing (not even the constructor) in the VM. Mine however calls the VM init block (which the `BaseActivity` sets up), and the getUser() function even though I ask for it to return dummy data. The only major difference I can see is mine is an Activity and Google is testing a Fragment, and the ViewModel mock function is using Niek Haarman's [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library.

LoginActivityTest.kt

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginActivityTest {

    private val email = "***********@gmail.com"
    private val password = "123456"

    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity::class.java)

    private lateinit var viewModel:LoginViewModel
    private val userData = MutableLiveData<Resource<User>>()

    @Before
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    fun init() {
        EspressoTestUtil.disableProgressBarAnimations(activityRule)

        Log.d("LoginTest Init", "vm mocked....")
        viewModel = mock()
        `when`(viewModel.getUser()).thenReturn(userData)
        doNothing().`when`(viewModel).setLogin(anyString(), anyString())

        activityRule.activity.viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
    }

    @Test
    fun loading(){
        //Given: our login event has been kicked off
        onView(withId(R.id.etEmail)).perform(replaceText(email))
        onView(withId(R.id.etPassword)).perform(replaceText(password))

        Log.d("LoginTest", "Posting loading value ")
        userData.postValue(Resource.loading(null))

        onView(withId(R.id.progress_text_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityLoginBinding, LoginViewModel>(), LoginNavigator {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
        internal set

    override val viewModel: LoginViewModel
        get() = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    private lateinit var activityLoginBinding: ActivityLoginBinding

    override val bindingVariable: Int
        get() = BR.viewModel

    override val layoutId: Int
        get() = R.layout.activity_login

    override val progressTextView: TextView?
        get() = activityLoginBinding.progressInclude?.progressTextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityLoginBinding = viewDataBinding
        viewModel.navigator = this

        Log.d("LoginActivity", "1 - onCreate, observing vm.getUser changes")
        viewModel.getUser().observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", "4 - onCreate, user change detected")

            activityLoginBinding.userResource = it
            it?.let {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "5 - onCreate, user change, not null: " + it)
                viewModel.login(it)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun login() {
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "2 - activity login() called, getting email + pass for vm")
        val email = activityLoginBinding.etEmail.text.toString()
        val password = activityLoginBinding.etPassword.text.toString()
        if (viewModel.isEmailAndPasswordValid(email, password)) {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", "3, setting email and pass on vm")
            viewModel.setLogin(password, email)

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.kt

```
@OpenForTesting
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(loginInteractor: LoginInteractor,
                                          schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider)
    : BaseViewModel<LoginNavigator, LoginInteractor>(loginInteractor, schedulerProvider) {

    @VisibleForTesting
    final var loginCredentials: MutableLiveData<Pair<String, String>> = MutableLiveData()
        set(value) {
            if (value.value === field.value) return
            field = value
        }

    final var user: LiveData<Resource<User>>

    init {
        Log.d("LoginVM", "* - Init block, shouldn't be here...")

        user = Transformations.switchMap(loginCredentials) {
        Log.d("LoginVM", "user switchmap returning " + it.first)

            if (it.first.isBlank() || it.second.isBlank())
                AbsentLiveData.create()
            else
            interactor.callServerLoginRepo(it.first, it.second)
        }
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun getUser(): LiveData<Resource<User>> {
        Log.d("LoginVM", "* - calling get User, shouldn't be here: " + user.value)
        return user
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setLogin(password: String, email: String) {
        Log.d("LoginVM", "* - calling setLogin, shouldn't be here")
        loginCredentials.value = Pair(password, email)
    }

    fun onServerLoginClick() {
        navigator?.login()
    }

    override fun onUnknownError(message: String) {
        navigator?.handleError(message)
    }

    fun isEmailAndPasswordValid(email: String, password: String): Boolean {
        return email.isValidEmail() && password.isValidPassword(AppConstants.MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
    }

    fun login(resource: Resource<User>) {
        Log.d("LoginVM", "* - vm login resource: " + resource)

        if (resource.status == Status.SUCCESS && resource.data != null) {
            //Login success
        }
        else if (resource.status == Status.ERROR){
            resource.message?.let {
                navigator?.handleError(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat after running test:

```
04-20 14:25:45.769 1635-1650/? I/TestRunner: started: loading(app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivityTest)
04-20 14:25:45.771 1635-1650/? I/ActivityTestRule: Launching activity: ComponentInfo{app.core.sdk/app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivity}
04-20 14:25:45.826 1635-1635/? D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivity@9ab279d in: PRE_ON_CREATE
04-20 14:25:45.931 1635-1635/? D/LoginVM: * - Init block, shouldn't be here...
04-20 14:25:45.932 1635-1635/? D/LoginActivity: 1 - onCreate, observing vm.getUser changes
04-20 14:25:45.932 1635-1635/? D/LoginVM: * - calling get User, shouldn't be here: null
04-20 14:25:45.935 1635-1635/? D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivity@9ab279d in: CREATED
04-20 14:25:45.936 1635-1635/? D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivity@9ab279d in: STARTED
04-20 14:25:45.937 1635-1635/? D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivity@9ab279d in: RESUMED
04-20 14:25:46.518 1635-1650/? D/LoginTest Init: vm mocked....
04-20 14:25:47.290 1635-1650/app.core.sdk D/LoginTest: Posting loading value 
04-20 14:25:47.317 1635-1635/app.core.sdk D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivity@9ab279d in: PAUSED
04-20 14:25:47.401 1635-1650/app.core.sdk I/TestRunner: failed: loading(app.core.sdk.ui.login.LoginActivityTest)
```

**Edit:**
It looks like the issue here is that the VM is not correctly mocked. There's a couple related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513349/espresso-dagger2-set-viemodelprovider-factory-on-baseactivity) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533989/inject-viewmodelfactory-provider-in-activity-for-espresso-testing) which are having very similar problems. The injected VM factory is first used in the base activity's onCreate, but the activity needs to exist before we can override it to use our mocked VM.

Comment: According to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397895/4232337 you need to not let the activityRule auto-instantiate, and launch it yourself, so that you can setup things before. In your case, that'd mean setting the ViewModelFactory BEFORE the activity is launched and its regular ViewModelFactory is used already.

Comment: Interesting. I've tried instantiating the activity myself like you said but it didn't help. Thanks though - here is what the test looks like: https://pastebin.com/m7MbLgze

Comment: I might have misunderstood setting the vm factory before the activity is launched part, I can't call `activityRule.activity.viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)` before the activity is launched because the activity would be null

Comment: You don't have to. What the link says is that `@Rule` are executed before `@Before`, hence by the time you're trying to mock the Factory, the Activity is already there. The suggestion is to 1. Not launch the activity straight up (by the false flag in the Rule), 2. In `@Before` mock the viewModelFactory and 3. In `@Before` launch the activity

Comment: Sorry forgive my stupidity I've honestly read your comment 20 times and that does sound like precisely what I'm doing in that pastebin link in my first reply, what do you think?! I'm starting to think maybe this isn't related now, the issue is that the `getUser()` method is being called at all, so I don't see how the order of things being instantiated relates, but it's hard to tell!

Comment: Sorry you're right. Have you considered then another approach, where you'd mock the Module produced by Dagger directly? (The one that injects the Factory inside the Activity). Here's an example: https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-testing-using-dagger-2-mockito-and-a-custom-junit-rule-c8487ed01b56 (under the "espresso test" paragraph)

Comment: Thanks @NSimon you are basically correct I think. I've retitled the question as the problem seems fairly unresolved in the community.